# Numpy function to check `>=0` with tolerance for floating point error

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, constraints, precision

Using numpy, our optimization solver has a function that checks the feasibility of a solution by computing the slacks for the constraints, in the form of matrices and vectors.

We test feasibility using code such as:

```
    return np.all(slacks_x >= 0) and np.all(slacks_u >= 0)
```

This has a bug, because sometimes the slacks can take values like `-1.5 e-12` i.e. close to zero but negative due to floating point errors. In this case it erroneously returns `False`.

Is there a function in numpy that can check `>=0` with tolerances? Current workaround is to check `>= -0.1`.

Comment: Use `np.allclose()`?

Comment: Sounds like you already came up with that function yourself? That's just a "tolerance of 0.1".

Comment: @Divakar wouldn't that be equivalent to `==0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to use machine epsilon `np.finfo(np.float32).eps` or  `np.finfo(np.float64).eps`, and then return something like:

```
eps = np.finfo(np.float32).eps #np.finfo(np.float64).eps
return np.all(slacks_x >= -eps) and np.all(slacks_u >= -eps)
```